# passing variable from JavaScript to Django view

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

**
I'm having a variable in Javascript which is needed to send in Django view.py to perform some operations. Is there any way I can send that variable to Django View?
**

Comment: You could use a form and use JS to set the value of an input, or add the js variable as a parameter to the url.

Comment: Or you could use Ajax, which is the most natural way if a form isn't appropriate. You can't get away from making a request to your Django server.

Comment: The problem is I have 3 forms and one button which is not in the form. On that button click, I called the JS to gather all the values and store them in one variable. I want that variable to be in the Djano How can I do that?

Comment: [`fetch` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)